# Oracle sql regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string like this `'abc : efg : xyz'` for a column in a table, all the records for this column will be like this. I want substring of this string after the last colon(:). Please do need ful help

example:

```
'abc : efg : xyz'  -> xyz  </br>

'abc : efg : efghj'-> efghj
```

I have query for this as below, but I want shorter then this query:

```
SELECT REPLACE (
          REGEXP_SUBSTR (
             'abc : efg : xyz',
             ':.*$',
             REGEXP_INSTR (
                'abc : efg : xyz',
                ':',
                1,
                  LENGTH ('abc : efg : xyz')
                - LENGTH (
                     REPLACE ('abc : efg : xyz',
                              ':',
                              NULL))),
             1),
          ': ') data_after_the_last_colon
  FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (INPUTSTR, '^([^:]+ : )*', '')
```

Specifically, this seeks a string starting from the beginning (initial caret `^`) with zero or more occurrences of a string with non-colons (`[^:]+`) followed by  `:` .  It replaces all of these leading strings terminated with the space-colon-space with an empty string.

The following query demonstrates how this works.  I've used a factored subquery with your sample input and a half dozen other tests, and the query output has the input, my regexp_replace result, and your `REPLACE (REGEXP_SUBSTR` syntax (I replaced your `' abc : efg : xyz '` with the factored subquery).  You can add another test case by duplicating the `union all select` line and changing the string for `inputstr`.

Oh, about `doold` -- your syntax couldn't handle an input string without a colon, it would throw an error that killed all query results.  So I wrapped your syntax in a `DECODE (doold` to get all the rows back.

```
with sampl as (
  select           'abc : efg : xyz' as inputstr, 1 as doold from dual
  union all select 'z : b :' as inputstr, 1 as doold  from dual
  union all select 'z : b : ' as inputstr, 1 as doold  from dual
  union all select ' : a ' as inputstr, 1 as doold  from dual
  union all select ' a ' as inputstr, 0 as doold  from dual
  union all select '' as inputstr, 1 as doold  from dual
  union all select ' hij : klm : nop : qrs : tuv' as inputstr, 1 as doold  from dual
)
SELECT 
  inputstr,
  regexp_replace (inputstr, '^([^:]+ : )*', '') as bettr,
  decode (doold, 
      1, -- the following is your original expression, for comparison 
         -- purposes, edited only to replace 'abc : efg : xyz' with inputstr
         REPLACE (
          REGEXP_SUBSTR (
             inputstr,
             ':.*$',
             REGEXP_INSTR (
                inputstr,
                ':',
                1,
                  LENGTH (inputstr)
                - LENGTH (
                     REPLACE (inputstr,
                              ':',
                              NULL))),
             1),
          ': '),
          'Sorry the syntax won''t support input "' || inputstr || '"'
    ) data_after_the_last_colon
  FROM sampl
 order by doold desc, length (inputstr)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say the pattern is fixed, reversing the string and looking for and getting a substring till the first semi-colon would be the easiest. You can also use `trim` to eliminate any leading/trailing spaces.

```
select reverse(substr(reverse('abc : efg : efghj'),
          1,instr(reverse('abc : efg : efghj'),':')-1)) from dual
```

Comment: Unfortunately `REVERSE` is undocumented in Oracle.

Comment: @JonHeller..Please go through this..https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-functions.html#function_reverse

Comment: That document is for MySQL.

Comment: i suggest you try it for yourself

Comment: It works for now, on my system.  But it may not work on other systems, or in the future.  Oracle has shown a willingness to remove undocumented features regardless of their popularity.  For example, WM_CONCAT was an undocumented but popular function, and was removed in 12c.  If the function is not listed [in one of the manuals](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) it's probably not safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

If the position parameter of the [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions073.htm#i77598) function is negative it will count back from the end of the string. So you could use something like this:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR('abc : efg : efghj',INSTR('abc : efg : efghj',':',-1) + 1))
FROM   dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.  This works with NULL list elements too:

```
SQL> with tbl(row_nbr, str) as (
  2  select 1, 'abc : efg : xyz' from dual
  3  union
  4  select 2, 'abc : efg : efghj' from dual
  5  union
  6  select 3, 'abc :  : efghj' from dual
  7  )
  8  select row_nbr, regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)( : |$)', 1, regexp_count(str, ' \: ')+1, null, 1)
  9  from tbl
 10  order by row_nbr;

   ROW_NBR REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR
---------- -----------------
         1 xyz
         2 efghj
         3 efghj

SQL>
```

If you want to parse the entire list:

```
SQL> with tbl(row_nbr, str) as (
  2  select 1, 'abc : efg : xyz' from dual
  3  union
  4  select 2, 'abc : efg : efghj' from dual
  5  union
  6  select 3, 'abc :  : efghj' from dual
  7      )
  8  SELECT row_nbr, str,
  9             COLUMN_VALUE AS match_nbr,
 10            REGEXP_SUBSTR( str ,'(.*?)( : |$)', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) AS match_value
 11     FROM   tbl,
 12            TABLE(
 13              CAST(
 14                MULTISET(
 15                  SELECT LEVEL
 16                  FROM   DUAL
 17                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( str ,' : ' )+1
 18                ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
 19              )
 20            );

   ROW_NBR STR                MATCH_NBR MATCH_VALUE
---------- ----------------- ---------- -----------------
         1 abc : efg : xyz            1 abc
         1 abc : efg : xyz            2 efg
         1 abc : efg : xyz            3 xyz
         2 abc : efg : efghj          1 abc
         2 abc : efg : efghj          2 efg
         2 abc : efg : efghj          3 efghj
         3 abc :  : efghj             1 abc
         3 abc :  : efghj             2
         3 abc :  : efghj             3 efghj

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```